# Calculate variance in sqlite

Tags: sql, sqlite, aggregate, variance

I'd like to calculate the variance of a table column.
E.g. the formula to calculate the variance contains aggregate
and scalar functions and is:

```
(SUM((var-AVG(var))*(var-AVG(var))))/(COUNT(var)-1)
```

where var is the variable-column to calculate the variance.

What is the best way to use this function in Sqlite, like:

```
SELECT (SUM((var-AVG(var))*(var-AVG(var))))/(COUNT(var)-1) AS Variance FROM
TableX
```

Comment: You need sub-queries to handle the aggregation. Check out an example at http://support.microsoft.com/kb/175955

Answer (score 4):

The value of `AVG(var)` is to be used in each expression to be summed, so you have to compute it separately with a subquery:

```
SELECT SUM((var-(SELECT AVG(var) FROM TableX))*
           (var-(SELECT AVG(var) FROM TableX)) ) / (COUNT(var)-1) AS Variance
FROM TableX
```

Answer (score 0):

In partial response to CL's answer above, I am not sure whether the SELECT AVG(var) FROM TableX is cached or calculated twice (because it appears twice). For large tables/ views, this may become an issue. You may like an alternative:-

```
SELECT diff_squared / [n-1] FROM
(
    SELECT diff * diff AS diff_squared FROM 
    (
        SELECT x - mean AS diff FROM 
        (
            SELECT [Var] AS x FROM TableX
        ) innerData
        LEFT JOIN
        (
            SELECT avg(x) AS mean FROM
            (
                SELECT [Var] AS x FROM TableX
            ) 
        ) stats
    ) outerData
) LEFT JOIN
(
    SELECT count(x) - 1 AS [n-1] FROM 
    (
        SELECT [Var] AS x FROM TableX
    )   
) nMinus1
```

Answer (score 0):

I needed to calculate 5min averages, and wanted to calculate the variance, on those same 5min intervals.

In short :

1. create a view of the 5min averages
2. use this view to compute the variance much like CL above in this thread, although I don't agree with the -1 in `COUNT()-1`.

Maybe not very elegant, but easier for me to catch. I checked the results with LibreOffice Calc (VAR.P function).

**The data**

The data are in a table called `magic`.

```
CREATE TABLE magic(
  "dt" TEXT,
  "qccm" REAL,
  PRIMARY KEY (dt)
);
```

**Create a view of the 5min averages**

```
CREATE VIEW v_magic5m(
"dt",
"qccm",
)
AS SELECT
datetime(round(cast(strftime('%s',dt) AS INT)/300)*300, 'unixepoch') AS rndtime,
avg(qccm),
GROUP BY rndtime;
```

**Calculate the variance**

```
WITH tmp
AS (
    SELECT
    datetime(round(cast(strftime('%s',dt) AS INT)/300)*300, 'unixepoch') AS rnd_dt, 
    qccm
    FROM magic
)
SELECT
    tmp.rnd_dt,
    v_magic5m.qccm AS avg_qccm,
    SUM( (tmp.qccm - v_magic5m.qccm)*(tmp.qccm - v_magic5m.qccm) ) / COUNT(tmp.qccm) AS var_qccm
FROM tmp
LEFT JOIN v_magic5m ON tmp.rnd_dt=v_magic5m.dt
GROUP BY tmp.rnd_dt;
```

And the output looks like this :

```
rnd_dt               avg_qccm          var_qccm        
-------------------  ----------------  ----------------
2021-04-28 09:55:00  334.292929292929  765.924293439445
2021-04-28 10:00:00  332.743333333333  571.924122222222
2021-04-28 10:05:00  333.04            501.165066666667
```